# How to pass data using jQuery/ Ajax to a URL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

How to pass the fetched data using $.get() from a URL to a particular URL with query_string that can be retrieved  using $_GET() in PHP. I'm using following but not working. I want to pass the fetched data into following parameter http://example.com/data?data=FETECHED_DATA

```
<?php
$ip_address=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];    
echo '<script>
$.get( "http://ipinfo.io/'.$ip_address.'/org", function( data ) {
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "http://example.com/data",
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
});
</script>';?>
```

Well, don't recommended PHP to fetch and send data

Comment: You're using `$.get` and wrapping `$.ajax` inside. This is not intended to be used this way. You don't need `$.ajax`, because `$.get` is a shortcut for this. And please indent your code properly. Thanks.

Comment: Can you re-write please

Comment: data: "data="+data, - should pass your received data as get request but as people said - you need to rewrite it

Comment: Last thing first: please indent the code in your question (add 4 spaces for every block). This makes the code more readable. The chances are higher someone will help you, if the people can read your code with ease.

Comment: @cezar, nothing wrong with doing a $.ajax inside a $.get if that's what is required. That snippet is trying to get the "org" of an IP from ipinfo.io and using it in an ajax call to example.com/data with the end result processed by a function (not shown) called success

Comment: And now the jQuery stuff: this is a link to the documentation for `jQuery.get` ($.get) : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/. And here is a link to the documentation for `jQuery.ajax` ($.ajax): http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/. You're using `$.ajax` inside `$.get`. Correct this according to the documentation.

Comment: @JaromandaX It doesn't look to me, as if it is necessary to use both methods this way. And it makes the code unnecessary complicated and harder to debug. Using only `$.get` should be fine.

Comment: @cezar - no issue, he's doing a $.get when appropriate, and a $.ajax when appropriate, and nothing wrong with nesting the calls like that at all

Comment: @JaromandaX Actually you're partially right. He makes GET requests to two different URLs. But then why not being consistent and using `$.get` throughout the code. He could wrap another `$.get` instead of `$.ajax`. I'm interested if there is any good reason for mixing them and wrapping them this way.

Comment: @cezar, I actually found the intent clear because of how it was written

Comment: It'd be useful to see what `FETCHED_DATA` is.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this will do what you want

```
<?php
$ip_address=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];    
echo '<script>
$.get("http://ipinfo.io/'.$ip_address.'/org", function(data) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://example.com/data",
        data: {data : data},
        success: success,
        dataType: dataType
    });
});
</script>';?>
```

the only change is **data: data** changed to **data: {data: data}**

that's a lot of data :p

see this cut down mock up, http://jsfiddle.net/cm8o5dk8/ if you have a decent browser that can show you the network "usage" you'll see that the mockup fails trying to GET `http://example.com/data?data=AS15169+Google+Inc.%0A` - the %0A comes back from ipinfo.io

Comment: It is not passing the fetched info in the URL http://example.com/data?data=FETECHED_DATA

Comment: My apologies - jQueery changes it's behaviour every minor release, so I'm probably 1000 behaviours behind since last year

Comment: `url: "http://example.com/" + data,` ??? Or stands data in the URL for some example parameter?

Comment: just tested - the code I posted is SOUND and works and DOES try to get `http://example.com/data?data=FETCHED_DATA` - any failure is due to you not having a success function defined or the dataType defined corectly

Comment: @cezar - read the $.ajax documentation you linked to, find the section explaining the "data" parameter, you'll see why my code is correct

Comment: I want to pass the data in following manner http://example.com/data?data=" + data

Comment: My solution does that

Comment: @Disk01 - What version of jQueery are you using?

Comment: @Disk01 - more importantly, is there a function called `success` and a variable called `dataType` in your javascript - if not, then these need to be defined for you to have any chance of success

Answer (score 0):

Thanks it worked

```
$.get("http://ipinfo.io/8.8.8.8/org", function(data) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://example.com/data",
        data: {data : data},
        success: function() {},
        dataType: 'json'
    });
});
```